# very high memory page in rates in the database server

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, redhat

Very high page in rates obsorved in the database server, server environments and observations are as listed below:

**Server Environment:**

OS Release - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)/ 
System Info - Linux database.esewa.com.np 2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 31 11:37:10 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
RAM - 32G(22G=MYSQL, 2GB=MEMCACHE and rest is given to OS)
HW - 2Sockets - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
Storage - 10K RPM disks with RAID 10 in disk bays

**Observation against MEMORY PAGE IN**

Assuming that PAGE IN value should be 0 or low and hitting greater than 25 indicates is very high or memory under pressure and may be precursor to swapping. I have obsorved very high page(Maximum-180) in rates in the server but didn't see any memory process swap queue. Also noticed mostly 99% IO utilization though other metrics are normal(avg-cpu: %user(10.47) %nice(0.00) %system(0.63) %iowait(5.26) %steal(0.00) %idle(83.64))

**Questions:**

Is the assumption is reasonable in this context?

Did we allocate more memory to the the application(i.e. 22G-MYSQL and 2GB MEMCACHE)?

Anybody see issue with the combination of MYSQL and MEMCACHE for very high page(Max-180) in rates?

Can hugepages help to address this issue?

Behavior of hitting device utilization(%util of iostat) closer to 99% most of the time is acceptable in this context?

I'd appreciate if anyone provide constructive and critical answer for above questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> Can hugepages help to address this issue?

Yes, hugepages is recommend for performance tuning of database. This is also recommended from this [link - Enabling Large Page Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/large-page-support.html)

> Is the assumption is reasonable in this context?

Your assumption about page-in is incorrect. The page-in and page-outs would be high when kernel is doing I/O, as data is read from the disk and moved into the main memory, vis-a-vis, pages are being swapped causing high read and write I/O operations.

Refer `man sar`:

"

pgpgin/s

Total number of kilobytes the system paged in from disk per second.

pgpgout/s

Total number of kilobytes the system paged out to disk per second.

"

> Behaviour of hitting device utilization(%util of iostat) closer to 99% most of the time is acceptable in this context?

You may also want to look into the [mysql tuner](http://www.mysqltuner.com) for configuring the read/key/sort buffer sizes and  Tune the system to an use deadline I/O scheduler for database. Use `tuned-adm` or manually `echo 'deadline' > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` or set `elevator=deadline` in `grub.conf` to make this persistant.

Additionally, look into the below kernel tunables and set them in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or using `sysctl` to minimize unnecessary swapping of pages, keep the dirty page ratio low, between 5 to 10%, determines how long dirty pages can be kept in cache before being expired. Note: these values must be dealt with care, make incremental changes and test the load on the server.

```
vm.swappiness              
vm.dirty_background_ratio  
vm.dirty_ratio
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs
```

Comment: Thank you askb for the reply, it includes convincing tools/methods. I will do my experiments with your proposal and get back to you with my feedback.

Comment: @Suresh I have added some kernel tunables which you may want to look into further.

Comment: Thanks for reminding about sar command, "sar -B" gives pgpgin/s and pgpgout/s and I have obsorved Page In(Min-0.27, Max-3920.37, Avg-162.63)/Out(Min-152, Max-832.86, Avg-416) benaviour of the system, there were situations of having significant fault/s(Min-924, Max-1070.34, average-943) and Major Faults-majflt/s(Min-0.01, Max-1.43, Avg-0.11). I didn't noticed high number of major faults here which indicates that process execution is not interrupted to often to wait for disk I/O to complete redaing pages and significant minor fault(fault/s) which are not causing disk I/O.

Comment: Regarding verifying mysql configurations using mysqltuner, I have tried long time back and sized mysql configurations based on the suggestions produced by mysqltuner.

I am going to experiment with the deadline scheduler and sysctl parameters, will share the findings very soon. Thanks.

Comment: Excessive swapping?  Lower `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Huge pages?  That will cut down CPU time a small amount, but only complicate the swapping situation.